# kubernetes ingress config for jenkins says service doesn't exist

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

I have a Jenkins setup which is inspired by this guide.

I wanted to add an url, so I added An ingress.yaml.
jenkins is still available at <node_url>:32000 but not at http://jenkins.localdomain (where /etc/hosts has ) been updated with the IP of the node running Jenkins.
What Am I missing?

### $ cat ingress.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: devops-tools
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: 'websecure'
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: jenkins.localdomain
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: jenkins-service
                port:
                  number: 32000
```

### $ cat service.yaml

```yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
  namespace: devops-tools
  annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
      prometheus.io/path:   /
      prometheus.io/port:   '8080'
spec:
  selector:
    app: jenkins-server
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: httpport
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 32000
    - name: jnlpport
      port: 50000
      targetPort: 50000
```

### EDIT #1

I tried changing the port to 8080 as suggested, but portainer apparently doesn't like it (and it doesn't work)

How it looks in the select service part of portainer's ingress page:
[image: portainer edit ingress]
How it looks in the select service part of portainer's service page:
[image: portainer service]

Answer (score 1):

Try change the port number in `ingress.yaml` to `8080` as that is the port on which the *jenkins-service* service is available within the cluster. The *NodePort* is a port on the cluster nodes themselves which would hairpin the ingress traffic. *NodePort*s are meant for use with loadbalancing solutions external to the cluster.

```yml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-ingress
  namespace: devops-tools
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: 'websecure'
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: jenkins.localdomain
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: jenkins-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It didn't quite wrk as expected though (I have updated my question)